# File manager in Ubuntu 20.04 not showing thumbnails

Tags: filemanager, thumbnails

The file manager that came with my installation ("Simple file manager for Gnome") doesn't show thumbnails for jpg, png, and videos. I've gone to /Preferences/Search & Preview and made sure it's set to always show thumbnails but it doesn't. How can I fix this?

Comment: Silly question, but have you closed Files and reopened it since changing the preview setting?

Comment: Yes, and also rebooted.

Answer (score 10):

Install FFMPEG Thumbnailer

```bsh
sudo apt install ffmpegthumbnailer
```

Then close and reopen file manager. Thumbnails for most video files should generate now.

Otherwise, delete `~/.cache/thumbnails` and restart your computer

Comment: Doesn't work for me0

Comment: Worked for me on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Answer (score 4):

As I haven't been able to fix the issue, I installed Nemo as an alternative file manager and lo and behold, thumbnails are back on the menu! Nemo is a more elaborate and hence to me more useful file manager anyway. Note that in the software center it appears only as "Files" which is... err... unhelpful. In the description, the word "Nemo" is mentioned though so it's not that hard to find.

Answer (score 3):

I think there's a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/totem/+bug/1988100) either in `totem-video-thumbnailer` or `GStreamer`.

When you search for solutions, many of them suggest `ffmpegthumbnailer`.

I can't say whether it's a better, or a worse thumbnailer, but installing it *did* work for me.

The only caveat is that you seem to have to configure things to override the system default. I couldn't find what the default processing order is for conflicting thumbnailers in the same directory, but thumbnailers in `~/.local/share/thumbnailers` appear to take precedence over `/usr/share/thumbnailers`

Creating a link solved my problem:

```
ln -s /usr/share/thumbnailers/ffmpegthumbnailer.thumbnailer ~/.local/share/thumbnailers/ffmpegthumbnailer.thumbnailer
```

### A couple of notes:

1. Here is an excellent answer with a *swag* of background about [how thumbnailing hangs together](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1368910/how-to-create-custom-thumbnailers-for-nautilus-nemo-and-caja)
2. You may quit nautilus/nemo by running them with the -q flag

   ```
   $nautilus -q
   $nemo -q
   ```
3. Deleting the contents of `~/.cache/thumbnails` causes thumbnails to be rebuilt the next time they are needed

Comment: Similar to this answer, I removed the conflicting totem ffmpeg thumbnailer `rm /usr/share/thumbnailers/totem.thumbnailer` I then had to reinstall ffmpegthumbnailer since it was already installed `sudo apt install ffmpegthumbnailer --reinstall`. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: The trouble with modifying stuff in /usr/share is that you don't own it. Your changes can be overwritten by the system at any time. That is why I suggested that simply linking the ffmpeg thumbnailer in your local thumbnailers directory will have it found first and so be used instead of the totem one. No need to remove anything from /usr/share

Comment: yeah I tried that first but it didn't resolve it for some reason, it wasn't until I removed the totem file that thumbnails started to work, but I'm not sure why... yours is definitely a better solution.

Comment: Thank you Aaron. I have been struggling for a week now and this is the solution! I also just deleted Totem thumbs as I didn't have a thumbnailers dir in .local/share

Comment: @i9pp0 Just creating ~/.local/share/thumbnailers/ should have been sufficient I reckon.