# Video Thumbnails are not generating

Tags: nautilus, thumbnails

I upgraded to Ubuntu Desktop 22.04.1 from 20.04.1 a few months ago, I recently noticed that MP4 and MKV video files are not generating thumbnails for Nautilus anymore. WEBM files are working fine though.

I have `ffmpegthumbnailer` and `gstreamer1.0-libav` installed, I've tried deleting `~/.cache/thumbnails` as suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1034595/thumbnails-not-showing-in-video-in-ubuntu-18-04)

Totem is setup to generate them:

```
cat /usr/share/thumbnailers/totem.thumbnailer
[Thumbnailer Entry]
TryExec=/usr/bin/totem-video-thumbnailer
Exec=/usr/bin/totem-video-thumbnailer -s %s %u %o
MimeType=application/mxf;application/ram;application/sdp;application/vnd.apple.mpegurl;application/vnd.ms-asf;application/vnd.ms-wpl;application/vnd.rn-realmedia;application/vnd.rn-realmedia-vbr;application/x-extension-m4a;application/x-extension-mp4;application/x-flash-video;application/x-matroska;application/x-netshow-channel;application/x-quicktimeplayer;application/x-shorten;image/vnd.rn-realpix;image/x-pict;misc/ultravox;text/x-google-video-pointer;video/3gp;video/3gpp;video/3gpp2;video/dv;video/divx;video/fli;video/flv;video/mp2t;video/mp4;video/mp4v-es;video/mpeg;video/mpeg-system;video/msvideo;video/ogg;video/quicktime;video/vivo;video/vnd.divx;video/vnd.mpegurl;video/vnd.rn-realvideo;video/vnd.vivo;video/webm;video/x-anim;video/x-avi;video/x-flc;video/x-fli;video/x-flic;video/x-flv;video/x-m4v;video/x-matroska;video/x-mjpeg;video/x-mpeg;video/x-mpeg2;video/x-ms-asf;video/x-ms-asf-plugin;video/x-ms-asx;video/x-msvideo;video/x-ms-wm;video/x-ms-wmv;video/x-ms-wmx;video/x-ms-wvx;video/x-nsv;video/x-ogm+ogg;video/x-theora;video/x-theora+ogg;video/x-totem-stream;audio/x-pn-realaudio;audio/3gpp;audio/3gpp2;audio/aac;audio/ac3;audio/AMR;audio/AMR-WB;audio/basic;audio/dv;audio/eac3;audio/flac;audio/m4a;audio/midi;audio/mp1;audio/mp2;audio/mp3;audio/mp4;audio/mpeg;audio/mpg;audio/ogg;audio/opus;audio/prs.sid;audio/scpls;audio/vnd.rn-realaudio;audio/wav;audio/webm;audio/x-aac;audio/x-aiff;audio/x-ape;audio/x-flac;audio/x-gsm;audio/x-it;audio/x-m4a;audio/x-m4b;audio/x-matroska;audio/x-mod;audio/x-mp1;audio/x-mp2;audio/x-mp3;audio/x-mpg;audio/x-mpeg;audio/x-ms-asf;audio/x-ms-asx;audio/x-ms-wax;audio/x-ms-wma;audio/x-musepack;audio/x-opus+ogg;audio/x-pn-aiff;audio/x-pn-au;audio/x-pn-wav;audio/x-pn-windows-acm;audio/x-realaudio;audio/x-real-audio;audio/x-s3m;audio/x-sbc;audio/x-shorten;audio/x-speex;audio/x-stm;audio/x-tta;audio/x-wav;audio/x-wavpack;audio/x-vorbis;audio/x-vorbis+ogg;audio/x-xm;application/x-flac;
```

totem-video-thumbnailer is installed and seems to be fine

```
file /usr/bin/totem-video-thumbnailer
/usr/bin/totem-video-thumbnailer: ELF 64-bit LSB pie executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, BuildID[sha1]=6544369ec7ddf818eb0311a0c392511bbe3f194c, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, stripped
```

If I run it it produces the help output ok

```
/usr/bin/totem-video-thumbnailer
Usage:
  totem-video-thumbnailer [OPTION…] [INPUT FILE] [OUTPUT FILE] Thumbnail movies

Help Options:
  -h, --help                        Show help options
  --help-all                        Show all help options
  --help-gst                        Show GStreamer Options

GStreamer Options
  --gst-version                     Print the GStreamer version
  --gst-fatal-warnings              Make all warnings fatal
  --gst-debug-help                  Print available debug categories and exit
  --gst-debug-level=LEVEL           Default debug level from 1 (only error) to 9 (anything) or 0 for no output
  --gst-debug=LIST                  Comma-separated list of category_name:level pairs to set specific levels for the individual categories. Example: GST_AUTOPLUG:5,GST_ELEMENT_*:3
  --gst-debug-no-color              Disable coloured debugging output
  --gst-debug-color-mode            Changes colouring mode of the debug log. Possible modes: off, on, disable, auto, unix
  --gst-debug-disable               Disable debugging
  --gst-plugin-spew                 Enable verbose plugin loading diagnostics
  --gst-plugin-path=PATHS           Colon-separated paths containing plugins
  --gst-plugin-load=PLUGINS         Comma-separated list of plugins to preload in addition to the list stored in environment variable GST_PLUGIN_PATH
  --gst-disable-segtrap             Disable trapping of segmentation faults during plugin loading
  --gst-disable-registry-update     Disable updating the registry
  --gst-disable-registry-fork       Disable spawning a helper process while scanning the registry

Application Options:
  -s, --size                        Size of the thumbnail in pixels
  -r, --raw                         Output the raw picture of the video without scaling or adding borders
  -l, --no-limit                    Don't limit the thumbnailing time to 30 seconds
  -v, --verbose                     Output debug information
  -t, --time                        Choose this time (in seconds) as the thumbnail
  -p, --print-progress              Only print progress updates (can't be used with --verbose)
```

It's also enabled in the GUI preferences:
[image: Nautilus preferences]

Permissions are ok:

`-rw-rw-r--  1 baa baa    5433184 Mar 18 23:42  audio.mp4`

I am using an AMD CPU and an AMD GPU, using open source driers installed using the install script from AMD's website:
[image]

I ran `sudo dmesg -Hew` after clearing the thumbnail cache and visiting the folder again. I can see the icons flash as it tries to generate the new ones but they remain as the default video icon, no relevant logs appear.

Comment: Did you check nautilus preferences (Preferences -> Search & Preview) for thumbnails?

Comment: @ExploitFate There is no Search & Preview section but there is a likely Show Thumbnails which is turned on

Comment: Just in case, have you checked the permissions for the folder and video files with ```ls -hal``` ? It's not usual to have the video on a different FS, maybe a external HD or NFS network mount and permissions for your user may not allow creation of new files.

Comment: @CarlesMateo Permissions look ok, I have read and write permissions, this happens for files on any file system including my home folder. Webm files within the same folder have thumbnails without issue.

Comment: @Baa thanks. I was thinking, maybe Ubuntu 22.04 disabled the proprietary drivers. Can you check the Software & Updates config?

Comment: @CarlesMateo no proprietary drivers are available. Currently I have the open source AMD GPU drivers installed using the install script from the AMD website. I also have an AMD CPU.

Comment: @B Do you see anything abnormal in the Kernel? ```dmesg -T```

Comment: @CarlesMateo I cleared the thumbnail cache and visited the folder again while watching `sudo dmesg -Hew`, there doesn't appear to be anything relevant, mostly firewall logs.

Comment: @Baa Thanks. Nice. I would suggest clearing the thumbnails cache and attaching to the thumbnail generator process with System Trace ```strace PID```. Increase the length of the output or even better use -o to output to a file and take your time to check it.

Comment: @CarlesMateo how do I find the PID of the thumbnail generator process?

Comment: @Baa I don't know what's the best way, but if I had to troubleshoot this, I would clear the cache for thumbnails and then I'll watch the Open files with ```lsof``` greping with ```grep``` for the folder of the thumbnails. With this I would get the process name, and with this the PID usin ```ps -aux```. Probably it's a process in the background so hopefully you'll be able to attach it. Is more difficult if the thumnail generator processes are launched and end but can be done as well

Comment: Whoever closed the topic, unless you are saying there is a bug, I get the same issue with no thumbnails in Nemo as in Nautilus, 22.04 whereas in 20.04 I had thumbnails in Nautilus but not Nemo.

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/a/1426435/994753 for your solution. Unhelpfully, the answer was deleted here because it is valid for different questions.